# I'm using PhoneGap and in my pages I'm trying to use FontAwesome but it doesn't work?

Tags: android, html, css, cordova, font-awesome

I created application with PhoneGap for Android and I'm using FontAwesome icons in my app, but I can't see icons but just squares. I include FontAwesome like this

```
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css">
```

And I'm using it like this

```
<i class="icon-circle "></i>
```

Do I need to move the FontAwesome folder somewhere else, now it is in www->fontawesome and the file from which I'm calling it it's also in www folder,  or I need to do something else I can find any useful answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://github.com/FortAwesome/Font-Awesome/issues/1094

I think this explains it
You have to go into the font-awesome css and make a change to the line

```
  text-rendering: optimizelegibility;
```

change it to

```
  text-rendering: auto;
```

Answer (score 0):

I encountered this issue when I didn't include the *fonts* folder containing all the Font Awesome fonts.

Font Awesome looks for the fonts in a path relative to the `font-awesome.css` file (`../fonts/fontawesome-webfont.eot`, etc.).