# Font Awesome icons not rendering in Phonegap iOS application

Tags: javascript, ios, cordova, font-awesome

Rather then render the icons I am getting small squares:

[image: screen shot 2014-07-31 at 8 26 32 pm]

It works perfectly fine within the browser, but when I viewed my app in iOS Simulator or Mobile Safari, the squares were there.

Thanks so much for your help!

Comment: check this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17897285/im-using-phonegap-and-in-my-pages-im-trying-to-use-fontawesome-but-it-doesnt)

Comment: @BuDen I tried changing all references to optimizeLegibility to auto without any success

Comment: where are the fonts file located are they inside the phonegap app build or external(webserver)?

Comment: @frank They are in the same folder as the css file, into a subfolder called `fonts`.

Comment: @Karl a few days back a guy had a similar problem.([link here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25022589/font-awesome-4-1-0-not-working-in-cordova-android-emulator#comment38921411_25022589)). Can yo show us the lines in your index.html file where you have added the link tag for including the CSS file.? Also what files you have include for font awesome in your phonegap app?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

i had the same issue. I put the "font-awesome.min.css" file directly in my cordova ios xcode and than i called it in the "index.html" file, with:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/font-awesome.min.css">
```

after that i try to use the font awesome spinner instead the default jQuery Modile preloader, with this code even in "index.html" before jQuery Mobile call:

```
<script>
        $(document).bind( 'mobileinit', function(){
                         $.mobile.loader.prototype.options.text = "loading";
                         $.mobile.loader.prototype.options.textVisible = true;
                         $.mobile.loader.prototype.options.theme = "p";
                         $.mobile.loader.prototype.options.textonly = false;
                         $.mobile.loader.prototype.options.html = "<span class='ui-bar ui-overlay-c ui-corner-all'><i class='fa fa-spinner fa-spin fa-5x' style='color:#000;'></i></span>";
                         });
</script>
```

The result is the same a rotate square, Where i'm wrong?

Comment: FIXED by adding the "fonts" folder from Font Awesome directory, to the project directory "www" . Hope it will helpful

Answer (score -2):

First, install Font Awesome:

Download the latest [Font Awesome](http://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/assets/font-awesome-4.3.0.zip) version
Double-click fontawesome-webfont.ttf and install it on your laptop/desktop (optional)
Copy fontawesome.css to www/css
Remove the references to font files in fontawesome.css, i.e. remove @font-face declaration
Then in Xcode:

Copy fontawesome-webfont.ttf into “Your Project/Resources/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.ttf”
Add Font Awesome to the .plist file by selecting the “Info” tab
Add a new property named “Fonts provided by application” and set the value to “fontawesome-webfont.ttf”
Clean and build your project. Font Awesome is now ready to be used.

Phonegap example:
class="fa fa-cog"